# Class to make Web Service calls

Tags: c#, rest, client, xamarin

I've a web service class to handle all requests to the external service.

All the methods are very similar, so I want to refactor this into DRY code.

This is an app in Xamarin.Forms. I'm making the external api so if anything should be changed there I can.

```
class WebService : IWebService
{
    public WebService(IRestClient restClient, IConnectivity connectivity)
    {
        RestClient = restClient;
        Connectivity = connectivity;
    }

    IRestClient RestClient { get; }
    IConnectivity Connectivity { get; }
    string SessionId { get; set; }
    public bool HasSession => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionId);

    public ServiceResponse Login(string username, string password)
    {
        if (!Connectivity.IsConnected)
        {
            return new ServiceResponse
            {
                ErrorMessage = "No internet connection.",
                Success = false
            };
        }

        var request = new RestRequest("security/login", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("Username", username);
        request.AddParameter("Password", password);

        var response = RestClient.Execute<LoginResponse>(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            SessionId = response.Data.SessionId;
            return new ServiceResponse
            {
                Success = true
            };
        }
        else
        {
            var responseMessage = JsonUtils.DeserializeAnonymousType(response.Content, new { Message = "" });
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseMessage.Message))
                return new ServiceResponse
                {
                    ErrorMessage = responseMessage.Message,
                    Success = false
                };
            else
                return new ServiceResponse
                {
                    ErrorMessage = response.ErrorMessage,
                    Success = false
                };
        }
    }

    public ServiceResponse<IEnumerable<Scanner>> GetScanners()
    {
        if (!Connectivity.IsConnected)
        {
            return new ServiceResponse<IEnumerable<Scanner>>
            {
                ErrorMessage = "No internet connection.",
                Success = false
            };
        }

        var request = new RestRequest("scan/getscanners", Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("SessionId", SessionId);

        var response = RestClient.Execute<GetScannersResponse>(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return new ServiceResponse<IEnumerable<Scanner>>
            {
                Data = response.Data.Scanners,
                Success = true
            };
        }
        else
        {
            var responseMessage = JsonUtils.DeserializeAnonymousType(response.Content, new { Message = "" });
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseMessage.Message))
                return new ServiceResponse<IEnumerable<Scanner>>
                {
                    ErrorMessage = responseMessage.Message,
                    Success = false
                };
            else
                return new ServiceResponse<IEnumerable<Scanner>>
                {
                    ErrorMessage = response.ErrorMessage,
                    Success = false
                };
        }
    }

    public ServiceResponse<string> OpenScanningSession(ScannerType scannerType, Scanner scanner)
    {
        if (!Connectivity.IsConnected)
        {
            return new ServiceResponse<string>
            {
                ErrorMessage = "No internet connection.",
                Success = false
            };
        }

        var request = new RestRequest("scan/openscanningsession", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("SessionId", SessionId);
        request.AddParameter("ScannerType", scannerType.ToString());
        request.AddParameter("ScannerId", scanner.Id);

        var response = RestClient.Execute<OpenScanningSessionResponse>(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return new ServiceResponse<string>
            {
                Data = response.Data.ScanningSession,
                Success = true
            };
        }
        else
        {
            var responseMessage = JsonUtils.DeserializeAnonymousType(response.Content, new { Message = "" });
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseMessage.Message))
                return new ServiceResponse<string>
                {
                    ErrorMessage = responseMessage.Message,
                    Success = false
                };
            else
                return new ServiceResponse<string>
                {
                    ErrorMessage = response.ErrorMessage,
                    Success = false
                };
        }
    }

    public ServiceResponse<ScanBarcodeResult> ScanBarcode(string barcode, string scanningSession, ScanAction scanAction)
    {
        if (!Connectivity.IsConnected)
        {
            return new ServiceResponse<ScanBarcodeResult>
            {
                ErrorMessage = "No internet connection.",
                Success = false
            };
        }

        var request = new RestRequest("scan/scanbarcode", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("Barcode", barcode);
        request.AddParameter("ScanningSession", scanningSession);
        request.AddParameter("ScanAction", scanAction.ToString());

        var response = RestClient.Execute<ScanBarcodeResult>(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessful)
            return new ServiceResponse<ScanBarcodeResult>
            {
                Data = response.Data,
                Success = true
            };
        else
            return new ServiceResponse<ScanBarcodeResult>
            {
                ErrorMessage = response.ErrorMessage,
                Success = false
            };
    }
}
```

`ServiceResponse` classes:

```
class ServiceResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

class ServiceResponse<T>
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: All of the methods checking to see if they are connected seems ok to me, I would simply have some sort of local `ServiceResponse` field/constant which is returned if `!Connectivitiy.IsConnected` is false. Similarly, it might be worth creating a small helper method which takes in all of the required properties for creating a new `RestRequest` as well as an unknown number of header arguments ([params](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) might help with this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ternary Operator**

The operator `?:` could become very helpful to you as it allows you to inline an if-statement. [Microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). For example,

```
if (response.IsSuccessful)
    return new ServiceResponse<ScanBarcodeResult>
    {
        Data = response.Data,
        Success = true
    };
else
    return new ServiceResponse<ScanBarcodeResult>
    {
        ErrorMessage = response.ErrorMessage,
        Success = false
    };
```

Can become,

```
return new ServiceResponse<ScanBarcodeResult>
{
    Data = response.IsSuccessful ? response.Data : null, // null or w/e the default value is for its datatype.
    ErrorMessage = response.IsSuccessful == false ? response.ErrorMessage : null, // null or w/e the default value is for its datatype.
    Success = response.IsSuccessful
};
```

**CreateResponse Function**

You could create a private function for creating a response since it seems to be a pretty common and uniform action in your code. Something like this perhaps,

```
private ServiceResponse<T> CreateResponse<T>(T data, string errorMessage, bool wasSuccessful)
{
    return new ServiceResponse<T>()
    {
        Data = wasSuccessful ? data : default(T),
        ErrorMessage = wasSuccessful == false ? errorMessage : null,
        Success = wasSuccessful
    };
}

CreateResponse<string>(response.Data, response.ErrorMessage, response.IsSuccessful);
```

All this does is make it to where you have to type less, there will be some cases where you won't want to do this. I feel like the best way to know is experience :)

Doing something like this might make your code a bit more concise (and therefore readable) since you don't have to create a new ServiceResponse multiple times a function as you are doing now, which is multiple lines of code.

Hope these tips help or give you some of your own ideas!